# How do I take a user input and search through an arraylist in a different class for the user input?

Tags: java

Update:
After applying improvements suggested by @user27158 (thank you) i have come across another issue when i come to run the program.

An error pops up and essentially stops the program from continuing. After looking into this, I cannot figure out what the issue is.
Once again, i am new to programming and it is likely that i am just missing something completely simple.

Error Message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at country.game.EuropeanCountries.EuropeanCountriesList(EuropeanCountries.java:17)
    at country.game.Main.main(Main.java:36)
 Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 seconds)

The Error occurs at the line:

```
List<String> euCountries = EuropeanCountries.EuropeanCountriesList();
```

Main Class:

```
package country.game;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static List<String> EuropeanCountriesList() {
        List<String> EuropeanCountries = new ArrayList<>();
        return EuropeanCountries;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean Running = true;

        List<String> UsedCountries = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner Reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(Running == true){



            System.out.println("Pick a Country: ");
            String UserChoice = Reader.next();




            List<String> euCountries = EuropeanCountries.EuropeanCountriesList();

            if(!euCountries.contains(UserChoice)){
                System.out.println("That is not a valid country");
            } else {
                if(UsedCountries.contains(UserChoice)) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry you have already used that country");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Correct! That Country is in Europe!");
                    UsedCountries.add(UserChoice);
                }
            }
        }        
    }           
}
```

"Europe" class

```
package country.game;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Europe {

    private static final List<String> EuropeanCountries = Arrays.asList(
            new String[]{
                "Albania",
                "Andorra",
                "Austria",

                "Belarus",
                "Belgium",
                "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                "Bulgaria",

                "Croatia",
                "Czechia",

                "Denmark",

                "England",
                "Estonia",

                "Finland",
                "France",

                "Germany",
                "Greece",

                "Hungary",

                "Iceland",
                "Ireland",               
                "Italy",

                "Kosovo",

                "Latvia",
                "Liechtenstein",
                "Lithuania",
                "Luxembourg",

                "Malta",
                "Moldova",
                "Monaco",
                "Montenegro",

                "Netherlands",
                "Northern Ireland",
                "North Macedonia",
                "Norway",

                "Poland",
                "Portugal",

                "Romania",

                "San Marino",
                "Scotland",
                "Serbia",
                "Slovakia",
                "Slovenia",
                "Spain",
                "Sweden",
                "Switzerland",

                "Turkey",

                "Ukraine",

                "Vatican City",

                "West Russia",
            }
    );


    public static List<String> EuropeanCountriesList(){

    return EuropeanCountries;
    }    

}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use `contains` method of `ArrayList` class.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting, this is my first stack overflow post.

Comment: [java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), [Java code formating convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), [Java access modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). First read those, then check [ArrayList::contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) and think how and where you could use it.

Comment: When you edit the post does it notify people that the question is not completely answered?  or do i have to make another question?

Comment: Hi @HelpMePls. We are not notified when you make an edit, so it may be best to make a new post next time. Otherwise use the '@' with someone's name, or comment on an answer

Comment: @HelpMePls For your new problem it seems you are calling method ```EuropeanCountriesList()``` from class ```EuropeanCountries```. You haven't posted a class called 'EuropeanCountries' so are you sure this is what you want to do? If you want to call the ```EuropeanCountriesList()``` method in your main class, just call it without any class name in front (though this will give you an empty list at the moment), or to call the method you've defined in class ```Europe``` use ```Europe.EuropeanCountriesList()```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, there a few a few improvements that you should make in the code;

1. Running is never incremented so your while loop will never end
2. You only want to initialise the scanner once, so do it outside of the loop
3. You are trying to compare a String to an int
4. Your list 'UsedCountries' is generic. That's never a good idea as it doesn't restrict which types you can put into them which means you may have errors that only show up at runtime. It should be declared as `List<String> UsedCountries = new ArrayList<>();`
5. Variable and method names should start with lowercase
   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

The fix:
How to access the arraylist from your other class

- return it from your method
- work on the returned list

```
    public static List<String> EuropeanCountriesList() {
        // declaring as List as it is best to not tie yourself to a specific implementation
        List<String> EuropeanCountries = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
        return EuropeanCountries;
    }
```

then

```
    String UserChoice = Reader.next()
    List<String> euCountries = EuropeanCountries.EuropeanCountriesList();
    ...
```

The above code allows you to use the arraylist in your current code. I would suggest a few further improvements though

1. Once you have your list, just use the contains method instead of the for loops

```
    List<String> euCountries = EuropeanCountries.EuropeanCountriesList();
    // step 1 - check if it is one of the acceptable countries
    if (!euCountries.contains(UserChoice)) {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid country");
    } else {
        // step 2 - check if it has already been selected
        if (UsedCountries.contains(UserChoice)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry You Have Already Used That Country");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Correct! That Country is in Europe!");
            UsedCountries.add(UserChoice);
        }
    }
```

2. Instead of creating your list of countries every time that method is called, declare it once and return the stored list instead

```
public class Europe {
    private static final List<String> EuropeanCountries = Arrays.asList(
        new String[]{
            "Albania", 
            "Andorra",
            ...
        }
    );

    public static List<String> EuropeanCountriesList() {
        return EuropeanCountries;
    }
}
```

Hope this all helps

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been so helpful!